# setting a fixed scale for distinct graphic series on ggplot2/ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I've made a series of maps for monthly incidence. The idea is to make a gif.
The problem is that each plot was created independently with its own scale.
I'm using viridis in this case. Is there some way that keeps the same scale and ranges for all plots, even when a particular month (one plot) has no data on those scales?

This is what I've made:

```
library(ggmap)
library(sp)

murder <- subset(crime, offense == "murder")

murder <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(murder[,c("lon", "lat")], data=murder,
                                 proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))

p <- ggmap(get_stamenmap(bbox=c(left=min(murder$lon), bottom=min(murder$lat),
                                right=max(murder$lon), top=max(murder$lat)), zoom=12))

d <- unique(murder$month)

murder <- murder[!(murder$month=="january" & murder$hour>0 & murder$hour<17),]
murder <- murder[!(murder$month=="february" & murder$hour>110 & murder$hour<24),]
murder <- murder[!(murder$month=="march" & murder$hour>12 & murder$hour<17),]


for (i in d){
  murder2 <- murder[murder$month==i,]
  mapa <- p +
    geom_point(data=murder2@data, 
               aes(x=murder2@coords[,1], y=murder2@coords[,2], color=as.numeric(hour)), 
               alpha=0.5,size=7) +
    scale_color_viridis_c(option="C",breaks=c(0,2,4,8,12,16,20,23),
                          labels=c("00:00","02:00", "04:00","08:00","12:00","16:00","20:00","23:00"),
                          name="Hour",
                          guide=guide_legend( keyheight = unit(3, units = "mm"), 
                                              keywidth=unit(6, units = "mm"),
                                              label.position = "bottom", title.position = 'top', nrow=1,
                                              label.theme=element_text(size = 6,face = "bold",color = "grey2",family = "Gotham"),
                                              title.theme=element_text(size = 6,face = "bold",color = "grey2",family = "Gotham", hjust=0.5)
                          ))
  ggsave(filename=paste0(i,".png"),plot=mapa, bg="transparent", 
         width =15, height = 15, units="cm", dpi=200)
}
```

These are my results. The first plot (from March) has 8 values in its scale, while the second plot (form February) only has 2:

[image: Mar]

[image: Feb]

I want the same 8 values for each map. even when there is no observations within those values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the code within your for-loop with the following. Explanations in comments within:

```
# there's lat / lon info in the data file, no need to reference coords separately
murder2 <- murder[murder$month==i, ]@data 

# define hour as a factor here, with the same ranges & labels, for each loop
murder2$hour <- cut(murder2$hour, 
                    breaks = c(0, 2, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 23, 25), 
                    labels = c("00:00", "02:00", "04:00", "08:00", 
                               "12:00", "16:00", "20:00", "23:00"),
                    right = FALSE)

mapa <- p +
  geom_point(data = murder2,
             aes(x = lon, y = lat, color = hour)) +
  scale_color_viridis_d(option = "C", 
                        name = "Hour", 
                        drop = FALSE, # keeps unused levels in the legend
                        guide = guide_legend(keyheight = unit(3, units = "mm"), 
                                             keywidth = unit(6, units = "mm"),
                                             label.position = "bottom", 
                                             title.position = 'top', 
                                             nrow = 1,
                                             label.theme = element_text(size = 6, face = "bold",
                                                                        color = "grey2",
                                                                        family = "Gotham"),
                                             title.theme = element_text(size = 6, face = "bold",
                                                                        color = "grey2",
                                                                        family = "Gotham", 
                                                                        hjust=0.5)))
ggsave(filename = paste0(i,".png"), plot = mapa, bg = "transparent",
       width = 15, height = 15, units="cm", dpi = 200)
```

Separately, if the final goal is to make an animated gif, you may wish to check out the gganimate package instead. It automates a lot of the work involved in transitioning between different states.